# Python regexp obtain not matched content

Tags: python, regex, compilation, matching

I need to parse a line of text and separate in parts and add it to a list, thing that i was able to do with the help of re.parse('regexp'). The thing is that i get some text that i dont want that match on this, but i need to know where is it, and how to detect it and of course what is it, to show an error.

the code matches  and filters out all perfectly, the thing is i need to filter out the 12 and the 32 that are not matching the regexp

```
import re 

str = '12 32 455c 2v 12tv v 0.5b -3b -b+b-3li b-0.5b 3 c -3 ltr'
a=re.compile(r'[+-]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+\s*[a-z]+|[+-]?[0-9]*\s*[a-z]+')

r=a.findall(str)
print (r)
```

Initial String:

```
str= '12 32 455c 2v 12tv v 0.5b -3b -b+b-3li b-0.5b 1 3 c -3 ltr'
list parsed, correctly
['455c', '2v', '12tv', ' v', '0.5b', '-3b', '-b', '+b', '-3li', ' b', '-0.5b', '3 c', '-3 ltr']
list that i need as well and any other string not matched ie: (/%&$%)
[12, 32, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that if we might not want to collect the digits only, then we would be starting with a simple expression:

```
\b([\d]{1,}\s)\b|([\w+-.]+)
```

with two parts:

```
\b([\d]{1,}\s)\b
```

are our undesired digits, and

```
([\w+-.]+)
```

has our desired outputs.

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"\b([\d]{1,}\s)\b|([\w+-.]+)"

test_str = "12 32 455c 2v 12tv v 0.5b -3b -b+b-3li b-0.5b 3 c -3 ltr"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uYBFrz/1/)

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired and you wish to modify it, please visit this link at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/uYBFrz/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Impressive, i need to clarify, the numbers that are not required or errors is numbers followed by other thing than a string... so in the meanwhile i was able to substring the difference of the correctly parsed from the original string and replaced with a empty string leaving the errors only...

Answer (score -1):

I've solved this by myself by replacing the correctly parsed on the initial string, so i get the difference then split to get it as a list

```
str = '12 32 455c 2v 12tv v 0.5b -3b -b+b-3li b-0.5b 1 3 c -3 ltr'
a=re.compile(r'[+-]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+\s*[a-z]+|[+-]?[0-9]*\s*[a-z]+')
r=a.findall(str)
print (r)
errors = str
for t in r:
    errors = errors.replace(t, '', 1)
errors = errors.split()
print(errors)
```